# Combining IF and RIGHT functions in excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-tables

I'm a super novice, trying to navigate data analysis in Excel, so be kind! I need to combine the IF and RIGHT functions.

So it's a sales dataset with different products, I need to use the IF function to filter the products so it only applies to "Bikes". Then I need the last 2 characters of the Product Name column which represents the size of the bike.

I've got the RIGHT function to work by itself but I can't combine it with the IF function so it only applies to the bike products.

```
=RIGHT(L2,2)
```

If this makes sense to anyone please help!

Comment: Please provide some test data and expected output in the original post using [edit]

Comment: Check [https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/543042-if-right-formula.html](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/543042-if-right-formula.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(LEFT(A1, 5) = "Bikes", RIGHT(A1, 2), "")
```

Then just copy this down the range of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it when working within a table:

```
=IF([Product Category]="Bikes",RIGHT([Product],2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me.

```
=IF([@[Product Category]]="Bikes", RIGHT([@Product],2),"")
```